# How to keep a stationary motorcycle handle in the forward direction

Tags: mechanical

How to keep a stationary motorcycle handle in the forward direction if no force is applied to rotate it. I have seen such motorcycles in Arcade Game Parlours but I want to make such one for myself.

Comment: use a spring ...

Comment: Please elaborate how to use spring.

Comment: How far do the handles turn? you don't give that detail, so two coil springs one on each side - they have to be the same though or a flat spring between two stops.

Comment: The handlebar can turn 70 degree max  in either direction. Please provide some reference images of the items used and the layout. Sadly I not an engineer but can work with it if I can see some reference pics. Hope I clarify my situation.

Comment: Also the handlebar can be used by kids so the force to turn will be low compared to a adult.

Comment: "*Please provide some reference images of the items used and the layout.*" You didn't provide any images of your problem setup. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

So, 3 simple methods:

Note, the blue represents the forks and the green a fixed point on the frame.

1. the orange is a fixing on the forks and the red is a coil spring - as the forks get turned the spring gets stretched, need to choose a spring with sufficient force to overcome the friction in the system, too much and it will become difficult to move.
2. the red represents a flexible metal or other material bar - again the force needs to be considered and the length as 70 degrees will require a defined length.
3. the red represents two coil springs.

Other options is to use a coil spring that gets wound up by pulling a cable.

All variations on a simple theme.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the no 1. design. The orange fixing is to be attached at bottom  I suppose. Will the length of the fixing have impact on the springiness of the design. I suppose the longer fixing willing be better.

Comment: Also in 1,  the red item spring , instead  we can  use a coil spring that gets wound up by pulling a cable. The benefit of coil spring is we can attach  anywhere and the property of compression is long lasting.

Comment: @Manjinder  don't I mention that at the end of my answer?

Comment: You mentioned it. I was just clarifying if I am correct in understanding what you meant.  Also please clarify about the length of fixing I asked above.

Comment: Now you can do some drawings with dimensions and work out change in length cf changing angles and the fun of spring rates. You will need to find the normal force required to turn the handlebars.